# How to debug Samba/SMB/CIFS timing error

Tags: samba, cifs

I'd be grateful for help with the following which seems to be a timing issue:

The samba server is an Asustor FlashStor running ADM 4.2.5.RN33 and under the good the smbd 4.12.8. The client is an Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS (kernel 5.15.0-97-generic) in a Proxmox virtual machine. I am not sure which Ubuntu package is responsible for the client to be able to mount a samba share, I know samba-libs is installed in version 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5.

The client mounts a volume from the server using the mount command with file system type `-t cifs`.

After intensive data transfer over several minutes, the connection is lost and the client hangs badly, is unresponsive for minutes.

The logs on the client:

```
CIFS: VFS: \\(some IP) has not responded in 30 seconds. Reconnecting...
CIFS: VFS: \\(some IP) Send error in SessSetup = -11
```

Logs on the server:

```
## Selected protocol SMB3_11
smb2_validate_message_id: smb2_validate_message_id: client used more credits than granted, mid 3, charge 1, credits_granted 0, seqnum low/range: 3/0
```

When I add the mount options `echo_interval=30` or `echo_interval=10` the errors are much less prevalent, but still occur. It seems that the timeout seconds in the log is three times of what I set as the `echo_interval`.

When mounting the volume for the first time, the client also logs the following (not sure whether related):

```
CIFS: VFS: parse_server_interfaces: malformed interface info
```

Somehow server and client seem to be incompatible. What is going on here?

Comment: Credit issues looks like a common error to get with buggy SMB implementations. Make sure `cifs-utils` and/or `smbclient` are updated on the client? On the server side as well, it looks like the current ADM version is 4.2.7